GND plane between tracks or tracks closer enough to remove the GND tracks
I am working in a design with many signals, no high speed signals, just some switches signals and encoders tracks. However I had problems with the ground uniformity sometime ago, therefore I would like your help for the following way to design the tracks:

Between those two kinds of layout, which one would be better:

A: where the tracks are separate enough to let the ground plane pass between each track.
B: where the tracks are close enough to remove the ground plane between them.

Can you help me with some explanation of which one would be better? Any resource where I can get more theoretical information?

Please note that with speed of the signal, it's not the frequency that matters, but the speed of the digital edge. Even low speed buses and signals may have problems due to crosstalk, because a fast edge disturbs a nearby signal via capacitive coupling.

Both solutions are poor. You typically want a solid ground plane under the signals. Also, the ground plane is a separate layer. How are you "running a ground plane" between signals?

This video from Rick Hartley about PCB grounding and grounding in electronics in general is great if you want to learn more in details.
This one from Phil’s lab talks more about PCBs in general and how to improve your design.
But from what I know the A variant is better as it will prevent the interference and crosstalk between the tracks.

Sorry but this answer will become useless whenever those third-party links disappear or change. To make it useful you need to summarize the conclusion of the videos. Additionally they won't show up in the search result.

Well, those are learning videos aiming to expand overall knowledge, and I can’t really summarize a 2 hours lecture in few words. More on I already answered the question in few words and explained why.

Broadly in general: A. Depending on via density, this has the most shielding between traces.
For your described scenario: B.  While A might be strictly better in EMC terms, the amount by which it's better, depends on application, and other priorities may dominate.  Here, you don't need the shielding, it's not high speed, it's digital with generous thresholds, it's not going to notice what crosstalk manifests here.
I would prefer B in a 2-layer layout for several reasons:

If trace intersections are required, the tight bus has a smaller overlap area, with fewer stitching vias required.  (No intersection is shown in the screenshot, so this isn't strictly applicable.  But it may prove important later in layout, or over time as the design evolves.)
Layout density is greatly improved.  You don't show any nearby components here, which may suggest the board is wildly oversized compared to what is needed.  There can be mechanical reasons to keep a board large, and in that case you can do kind of whatever, but aside from that, smaller boards are cheaper, and smaller products are generally more appealing to customers/users.
Fewer stitching vias are required.  Personally speaking, I'm quite particular about where and how many vias I use, and spend a fair amount of time inspecting ground integrity and placing vias.  Busing traces simplifies design: there are fewer crossings to keep track of.  Mind, my priorities will be quite different from yours: in part, I use this time as an excuse to practice my analysis of ground connectivity, wave propagation, etc.

One would imagine vias cost some, as well; but this, actually, is rolled into the standard fab cost for most purposes, and only manifests as tooling cost plus production time either in ridiculously high hole counts (a proto service may ding you for adding a grid-of-holes prototype area) or high production volume (say 10k+/yr?).  This imagined cost might be a lie I tell myself, but I'm not such a fool to think it will ever pay off in comparison to the time I spend doing it. :) (Again, at least not until high quantities.)
Conversely, I would prefer A when routing many sensitive or high-speed signals, particularly analog RF, where the crosstalk between traces is likely to be quite important, and where the length of coupling is comparable to the wavelength of signals present (or a modest fraction thereof).  I think the number of situations where I would have to route such signals in parallel is very small, anyway (it's better to keep sensitive signals distant in general, and usually the signal flow path between building blocks is sparse, and highly localized, making this trivial).
This level of care is largely unnecessary for digital signals, as the noise margins are adequate: e.g. a 3.3V LVCMOS signal has a 30-70% threshold range, or a ~1V margin from an output logic-low/high (which quickly stabilizes to very near the supply rail).  You would need a full 30% coupling, from one trace edge transition, into the neighboring trace, to exceed this margin: whereas adjacent microstrip traces struggle to exceed 10% coupling, even for the low aspect ratio typical of 2-layer designs (i.e. ~10 mil trace width / ~62 mil substrate thickness).  (Typical coupling factors for the interleaved-ground design will be single percent or less.)
High-speed digital signals, anyway, are largely LVDS or relatives thereof; something differential and small-signal, anyways.  The differential pair covers for a lot of limitations that full-swing (LVCMOS, also SSTL and friends to some extent) signaling suffers from, which makes several Gbps possible even on such simple boards.  Such links also typically dispense with parallel signaling, but integrate ~simultaneous values into sequential frames or packets instead (serdes, or various comm standards), so that a single pair might obviate dozens of parallel signals otherwise.
That's not to say that digital signaling never requires care -- advanced high-speed interfaces go to great lengths to recover clock and data from the bit stream, to correct errors due to interference, and even compensate for channel characteristics (e.g. pre-shoot / overdrive to compensate for FR-4 losses; leading-edge blanking to suppress bounce; line coding to maximize data rate in given (signal) bandwidth; DC balancing and AC coupling for immunity from supply voltage domains and low frequency interference; etc.).  Any signal that doesn't go to such lengths, may have varying levels of sensitivity to them, and consequently require more care.  A precision timing signal, such as might be used in bespoke signaling or analysis equipment, will be very sensitive to jitter and both signal quality and interference need to be optimized.
LVCMOS is by far the most common signaling standard; generic GPIOs on MCUs, peripheral interfaces, old and new (CMOS and TTL) logic families, all fit under this umbrella.  Edge rate can be fractional ns, but mostly is several ns.  The most common connection topology is the source-terminated transmission line, where a pin driver plus resistor matches the trace's characteristic impedance, and reflections are handled automatically (at worst, schmitt triggers should be used for input pins placed midway along the bus; propagation was a major consideration for the design of the PCI (not -e!) bus, back in the day).  If you have long traces in a design (more than some single to tens of cm, say), consider adding a resistor in series with each drive pin on the trace/net, very close to each pin; this resistance can be increased when less bandwidth is required, to slow rise/fall time and reduce risk of EMC problems (particularly useful when logic signals transition onto cables; additional filtering may also be desirable).

It all depends on the edge rates of your signals and the coupling between your tracks. In a low-speed design first thing to do is actually slowing down the edges. Keep in mind that even with a "low-speed" I2C signal the fall times can be well below 1 ns with today's chips.
If you manage to lengthen rise and fall times to values well above 10 ns, cross-talk won't be a problem in many low-speed designs with practical geometries.
What I usually do in low-speed designs is to define a design rule that keeps ground planes something like 5 tracks widths away from tracks. This way you can keep good distance between tracks and don't have to worry about connecting all the small copper islands.
